# Dashes Are Stripped from Headers in nginx and haproxy

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I have what must be a dumb question, but I can't figure it out.

I am trying to add the following response header in either haproxy or nginx:

Cache-Tag: html

HaProxy:

```
http-response add-header "Cache-Tag" "html" if { hdr_sub(content-type) -i html }
```

nginx:

```
add_header "Cache-Tag" "html" always;
```

(These don't do exactly the same thing as the nginx one just always adds it. But ignore that part)

**The weird part is that I can add all of the following headers:**

- X-Cache-Tag: html
- CacheTag: html
- Cache_Tag: html

But not:

- Cache-Tag: html

If I try to add Cache-Tag it just doesn't appear.  Does anyone have any clue here?

Comment: This may be Cloudflare stripping that header instead of nginx or haproxy being the culprit. I will leave this here for other folks.

Comment: [*"the Cache-Tag header is removed before the response is sent to the website visitor. End users of a website therefore will never see the Cache-Tag header a Cloudflare-enabled website is using."*](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/206596608-How-to-Purge-Cache-Using-Cache-Tags-Enterprise-only-)